# what input x maximize activation function in an autoencoder hidden layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Hi when i am reading about Stanford's **Machine Learning** materials about **autoencoder**, found a formula hard to prove by myself. [Link to Material](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/unsupervised/Autoencoders/)

**Question is:**
" What input image x would cause ai to be maximally activated? "

Screen shot of the Question and Context:

[image: Screen shot of the Question and Context]

Many thanks to your answers in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this can be rigorously solved using KLT conditions and Lagrange multipliers, there is a more intuitive way to figure the result out. I assume that f(.) is a monotone increasing, sigmoid type of nonlinearity (ReLU is also valid). So, finding the maximum of w1x1+...+w100x100 + b under the constraint (x1)^2+...+(x100)^2 <= 1 is equivalent to finding the maximum of f(w1x1+...+w100x100 + b) with the same constraint.

Note that g = w1x1+...+w100x100 + b is a linear function of x terms (Name it as g, so later we can refer it by that). So, the direction of largest increase at any point (x1,...,x100) in the domain of that function is the same, which is the gradient. The gradient is simply (w1,w2,...,w100) at any point in the domain, which means if we go in the direction of (w1,w2,...,w100), independent from where we start, we obtain the largest increase in the function. To make things simplier and to allow us to visualize, assume that we are in the R^2 space and the function is w1x1 + w2x2 + b:
[image: Linear Equation]

The optimum x1 and x2 are constrained to lie in or on the circle C:(x1)^2 + (x2)^2 =1. Assume that we are on the origin (0.0). If we go in the direction of the gradient (blue arrow) (w1,w2), we are going to attain the largest value of the function where the blue arrow intersects with the circle. That intersection has the coordinates c*(w1,w2) and it is c^2(w1^2 + w2^2) = 1, where c is a scalar coefficient. c is easily solved as c= 1 / sqrt(w1^2 + w2^2). Then at the intersection we have x1=w1/sqrt(w1^2 + w2^2) and x2=w2/sqrt(w1^2 + w2^2), which the solution we seek. This can be extended in the same way to 100 dimensional case.

You may ask why we started at the origin and not any other point in the circle. Note that the red line is perpendicular to the gradient vector and the function is constant along that line. Draw that (u1,u2) line, preserving its orientation, arbitrarily with the constraint that it intersects the circle C. Then choose any point on the line, such that it lies within the circle. On the (u1,u2) line, you start at the same value of the function g, wherever you are. Then as you go in the (w1,w2) direction, the longest path taken within the circle always goes through the origin, which means the path you increase the function g the most.

Comment: Thank you for this explicit answer! I will also look into KLT and Lagrange. thks